# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable with Wapiti

Tags: python, security, wapiti

I am trying to scan my server for vulnerabilities and I'm using Wapiti to do it. Strangely, I get this error when I run it. What's wrong?

```
root@server [~/wapiti-2.3.0/bin]# python wapiti http://my.ip.address.here
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wapiti", line 41, in <module>
    lan.configure()
  File "/root/wapiti-2.3.0/wapitiCore/language/language.py", line 58, in configure
    lang = langCounty[:2]  # en
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable
root@server [~/wapiti-2.3.0/bin]#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the latest release.

However, the [current source](http://sourceforge.net/p/wapiti/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/wapitiCore/language/language.py#l54) has a fixed version:

```
if lang is None:
    # if lang is not specified, default language is used
    def_locale = locale.getdefaultlocale()
    langCounty = def_locale[0]   # en_UK
    if not langCounty is None:
        lang = langCounty[:2]  # en
```

It was [a bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/wapiti/bugs/20/), [fixed on 2013-10-21](http://sourceforge.net/p/wapiti/code/318/).

Comment: Ohhhh. That's it then. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Any idea how I can set the language myself to even avoid this error?

Comment: No idea. I've never heard of Wapiti before your question.

Comment: You could just change the code, or install the version from svn.

Comment: @user1227914 From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.getdefaultlocale), you could try setting an environment variable, for example: `set LANGUAGE=en_GB`